# Why is the GP7200-powered A380 fleet not grounded?

Tags: safety, airline-operations, airbus-a380

After the Qantas A380 engine failure, all Trent-powered A380s were grounded.[1](https://www.flightglobal.com/news/articles/qantas-justifies-a380-grounding-after-catastrophic-t-349348/)

After the Air France A380 engine failure, the GP7200-powered A380 fleet was *not* grounded.

Why were these two incidents handled differently? And what are the primary drivers for grounding a fleet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The one that decided to ground the fleet was Qantas. Qantas was having a new airplane model and potentially made a trade-off between having a not known design flaw and keep flying and the risk. At that time the A380 entered in service three years before and around 20 aircraft were in service with a mix of engines.

Today, there are 200 A/C in service for 10 years. The possibility of having a design flaw or an unknown problem is really low.

It was not a airworthiness directive as the directive was created [2 months after](http://avherald.com/h?article=44992a89&opt=0) in January 2011. Qantas starting to get back in service the airplanes on 27th November (incident was on 4th Novemeber)

Comment: It depends what the root cause was (and we don't know yet, for the GP7200 incident). For example, a fundamental design flaw is one thing, but some klutz mixing up the part numbers and using the wrong type of bolts or the wrong torque setting when maintaining a single engine would be no reason to ground the entire fleet - just check the bolts on everything the klutz might have touched recently! Even though no information has been *released,* its quite likely that Airbus and the EA have a pretty good idea of the cause within hours of the plane landing.

Comment: ... failures like this look spectacular, but the root cause might be quite simple, and you can learn a lot very quickly from a video link up (over a secure communications link!) between a roomful of specialists at Airbus and EA, plus somebody on the ground operating a hand-held video camera - and the major manufacturers have the systems in place to provide that level of technical support 24/7/365.